# Query Handling Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, rdbms, database

Please help me regarding query. I am pretty weak in DBMS.

I have a table `TBLParent` which has some rows as follows

```
pkParentId   FKProductId     Name
  1              5             P1
  2              5             P2
  3              3             P3
```

and I have another table `TBLChild` that consist of its children

```
pkId     fkParentId    ChildName
 1            1          C1
 2            1          c2
 3            2          c1
```

Now, question is I want Parent records and count of its children based on `productId`.

For example: I want to

```
select 
    TBLParent.pkParentId, TBLParent.FKProductId, 
    TBLParent.Name, 
    count of its children
where   
    TBLParent.FKProductId = 5
```

I tried like this

```
Select 
    count(TBLChild.pkId) AS total, 
    TBLChild.fkParentId    
from  
    TBLChild 
group by 
    TBLChild.fkParentId
```

but how can I attach records of parent table with this count?

This will give me count but How I will attach parent record with this count. I mean to say output would be

```
pkParentId   Name      Count
  1           P1         2
  2           P2         1
```

Please help please help please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT P.pkParentId
      ,P.Name
      ,COUNT(*)
FROM tblParent P
INNER JOIN tblChild C ON P.pkParentId = C.fkParentId
WHERE P.pkParentId = @yourValueHere
GROUP BY P.pkParentId, P.Name
```

Comment: But sir, i want to get records by fkParentId not by pkParentId like in above query SELECT P.pkParentId
      ,P.Name
      ,COUNT(*)
FROM tblParent P
INNER JOIN tblChild C ON P.pkParentId = C.fkParentId
WHERE P.fkParentId = @yourValueHere
GROUP BY P.pkParentId, P.Name

Comment: In the above query, fkParentId and pkParentId will be equal.  The "INNER JOIN" portion of the query is what does that for you.  Based on your sample output in your question this query will give you what you are looking for.

Comment: Okay sir According to you if I put  @yourValueHere=5, will it return me the required result. Sorry to disturb you again. but I got confused by your last answer.

Comment: Yes, I believe you will see what you're looking for.  If not I've misunderstood the question and we can keep working at it.

Comment: It is working as required,Sir.
but sir, can it be possible that if I have parent record and it do not have any child record then also, it should return parent  record with count 0  as in this query it is selecting records by inner join.I replaced inner join with left join, it returns record but it do not show it's count 0 Thank You .

Comment: select Parent.TextPrompt, Parent.pkMerchProductAttributeId, COUNT(*) Total
from tblMerchandiseProductAttribute Parent 
left join tblMerchandiseProductAttributeValue Child On Parent.pkMerchProductAttributeId=Child.fkMerchProductAttributeId
where Parent.fkMerchProductId=5 group by Parent.pkMerchProductAttributeId,Parent.TextPrompt

Comment: select Parent.TextPrompt, Parent.pkMerchProductAttributeId, SUM(CASE WHEN Child.fkMerchProductAttributeId IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total from tblMerchandiseProductAttribute Parent left join tblMerchandiseProductAttributeValue Child On Parent.pkMerchProductAttributeId=Child.fkMerchProductAttributeId where Parent.fkMerchProductId=5 group by Parent.pkMerchProductAttributeId,Parent.TextPrompt

Comment: Alternatively, you can get your initial result set of TextPrompt, pkMerchProductAttributeId, Total and left join to THAT from your Parent Table and select ISNULL(Total, 0) AS Total.